# Has anyone used CiviCRM on a 10" tablet?

Tags: 4.6, mobile, usability

I am working on a nightshelter signin application in CiviCRM, and the suggestion is to use a 10" tablet.  I'm not sure this would work although the menu is much simplified. (I have a 7" tablet and it would be pretty unusable on that). Has anyone used CiviCRM on a 10" tablet?  Was it usable?

Comment: I have never used CiviCRM on 10" tablet and I am not sure whether starting from the use case of 10" tablet is a good starting point. CiviCRM is a CRM and not a webapp. It is usually used to support organizations mean processes with contacts with their constituents. However their might be use cases where an app on a mobile is required. I would rather suggest then to make an app for this which connects with civicrm through the api.

Comment: +1 Jaap's comment and Xavier's answer: Build the interface you want to use on the tablet using CiviCRM + tools like Drupal Webform + Webform CiviCRM. Some aspects of CiviCRM aren't suited to tablet use, but you're trying to equip nightshelter workers with a tool to do _their task_, not to have them managing groups & sending campaign emails ...

Comment: Something could be developed using the JS or REST APIs that is more suited to the mobile screen for the specific task?

Answer (score 5):

The main factor is probably the resolution of the tablet rather than its size, but the UI is in general meant to be used with a keyboard and a mouse (or very very pointy fingers ;)

For the mobiles, they have been several projects to provide a subset of CiviCRM features available.

- One is cividroid, an android application from the latest google summer of code https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36037.0
- Another is an extension on the server that adds a few "mobile friendly" pages https://civicrm.org/extensions/civimobile

If the aim for the tablet is "only" to do the registration, using drupal as the CMS+bootstrap as the theme+webform+webform civicrm should allow you to have a user friendly form tailored to your need that will push the data in civicrm (create the contact, the activity and the case for instance), to be used later with the "full" civicrm from a laptop

X+

Comment: I tried a Samsung 12" tablet (the biggest popular size?) but the problem was not so much the screen resolution, which was ok-ish, but the pop up keyboard.  This had the effect of hiding part of the screen, of course, which made it very awkward to use in some situations.  So without mobile friendly pages, it's a non-starter for me.

Comment: Have you tried civimobile?

Comment: No, not tried Civimobile as this particular application needs some 'standard' parts of the UI.  But I will give it a try.